# How to make an icon clickable so it renders data below

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a react page that shows a list of "messages subjects" received and when you click the down icon the messages relating to that subject appear directly below. (Imagine to help explain, when the user clicks the down icon on the line with 'Christmas' a white space needs to appear directly below and BEFORE the line with the 'New Year' text, so I can then display the message body, etc for each message relating to that subject.

[image: example of react page]

Here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import "./Messages.css";
import { ReactComponent as DownIcon } from "../images/down-chevron.svg";
import Moment from 'moment';

class Messages extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const url =
      "<my url>" +
      this.props.location.state.userID;
    fetch(proxyurl + url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ data: data, isLoading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading ...</p>;
    }

    if (data.length === 0) {
      return <p> no data found</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
          <div className="messageSubjectHeader">
            <div className="innerMS">Message Subject</div>
            <div className="innerMS">Number of linked messages</div>
            <div className="innerMS">Latest message Date and Time</div>
            <div className="innerMS">View Messages</div>
          </div>
          {data.message_Subjects.map((ms) => (
            <div className="messageSubject">
              <div className="innerMS">{ms.subject}</div>
              <div className="innerMS">{ms.message_Chain.length}</div>
              <div className="innerMS">{this.getLatestMessageDateTime(ms.message_Chain)}</div>
              <div className="innerMS">
                <DownIcon className="innerMSDownIcon" />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  getLatestMessageDateTime(messageChain){
    const lastmessage = messageChain.length -1;

    Moment.locale('en');
    var dt = messageChain[lastmessage].dateTime;
    return(Moment(dt).format('ddd DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss'))
  }
}

export default Messages;
```

Comment: Add a `div` inside the loop and based on the button click, you have to show/hide the div. Where are you facing the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the selected record id in the state and Update the selected id on the click of view messages button. And also add a `Content Panel` inside the loop and toggle the visibility based on the selected recorded Id in the state.

```
 {data.message_Subjects.map((ms) => (
          <>
            <div className="messageSubject">
              <div className="innerMS">{ms.subject}</div>
              <div className="innerMS">{ms.message_Chain.length}</div>
              <div className="innerMS">{"12/08/2020"}</div>
              <div className="innerMS">
                <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(ms.id)}>
                  {this.state.selectedId === ms.id ? "hide" : "Show"}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            // show/hide the content based on the selection --> Content Panel
            {this.state.selectedId === ms.id && (
              <div className="content">{ms.description}</div>
            )}
          </>
        ))}
```

I have created a sample Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-hertz-x89p8?file=/src/App.js

Let me know if your use case is different.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have an [**`onClick()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) handler if you want something to happen when user clicks an element, and then define `handleOnClick()` elsewhere in the component.
2. And you have no sub-component for the messages of a particular dated group, so, you'll need to code that, too.

***Sub-Messages Component***

I see that you have not defined any sub-components for messages.  I don't know how your API works, so, I'll be general in that regard, but you'll want a `<DateMessages/>` component.  This should have a constructor and render like...

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {'messages':[]};
}

render() {
    return (
        this.state.map((message) => {
            return message.date + ' ' message.text;
        });
    );
}
```

Then, you'll need to populate this.  So, add it as a ref in your `<Messages/>` component, as a child of `<div className="messageSubject">`.  Since it starts out with no messages, it should come out as blank when appended to each date group.  That'll look like `datekey = ms.subject;` `<DateMessages ref={(instance) => {this.$datekey = instance}} />`.

***onClick Handler***

So, your `onClick` handler would look like: `<div className="messageSubject" onClick={(e, ms.subject) => this.handleOnClick(e, ms.subject)}>`.  You might have a handleOnClick() like...

```
handleOnClick(e, ms.subject) {
     var datekey = ms.subject;
     this.$datekey.setState(this is where an array of messages for datekey would be stored);
}
```

***Advantages***

Why do it this way?  By having the state accurately reflect the data that the user is seeing, you'll be taking advantage of all the speedups of using ReactJS.